# Align nav Items Right Inside Header

Tags: html, css, header, navigation, flexbox

I don't want to use Float properties.

I want to use these properties(link): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also I have commented the background image css3? which also I want to apply

My Code:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


html,
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: "Lato", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }


.wrapper{
 display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction:column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

.header{
    /*background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("logo.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment:fixed; */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }

.logo{
    height: 100px;
    width:auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}


.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    }


.main-nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FlexBox: HTML5 and CSS3 Fundamentals</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="header">
        <img src="logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">

        <nav>
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh and what about this?

Logo on the left and navigation on the right

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


html,
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: "Lato", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }


.wrapper{
 display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction:column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

.header{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("logo.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    }

.logo{
    height: 100px;
    width:auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
}


.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    }


.main-nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FlexBox: HTML5 and CSS3 Fundamentals</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="header">
        <img src="logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">

        <nav>
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hello dan, in this logo is also shifting to right along with the nav, I want logo on left and nav on the right.

Comment: Then you need logo on the left and navigation on the right but in the same row right? Sorry the question was not clear enough with that, i will edit my answer

Comment: Sorry Dan, if my question as not clear to you. "YES" I need logo on the left and navigation on the right but in the same row.

Comment: Hey Dan thanks.I was also trying and got up to the same code snippet! yeah... Should I Include normalize.css. I also want to build the footer but din't succeded.

Comment: It should be the same, just add this to the footer div and things inside should position as you want `justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;`

Answer (score -1):

```
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```

I just added this to .main-nav.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Thanks Dan, but [justify-content: flex-end;], takes the nav items to the end but below the logo on the next row, and not on the right side of the logo in the same row.

Comment: Ok done in a new answer, I didnt know you wanted it in the same row